# How to load .stl files in libgdx?

Tags: android, 3d, libgdx

I am trying to import models created in OpenSCAD into libgdx. OpenSCAD supports exporting to STL among other formats. I could not find any in-built loaders for STL in libgdx. fbx-conv also does not support converting stl into g3dj. Any suggestions on how to make this work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured out "one" way to do it. I used Blender to convert the file from STL to FBX and then used the [fbx-conv](https://github.com/libgdx/fbx-conv) tool to convert it into g3dj/g3db(both of these are supported by libgdx). Hope this helps someone.